# QGraphicsScene::itemAt() - how to recognize custom classes

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

i have a little problem

I am programming Petri Net simulator...

I have two different classes

```
    class PNItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
    ...
```

and

```
    class PNEdge : public QGraphicsLineItem
```

when i call...

```
    QGraphicsItem *QGraphicsScene::ItemAt(//cursor position)
```

, is it possible somehow to get to know, what item i have clicked on? resp. what item is given item by ItemAt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GraphicsItem::type()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type) is intended to be used to solve this problem.

So you would do something like this for example:

```
enum ItemType { TypePNItem = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 1,
                TypePNEdge = QGraphicsItem::UserType + 2 }

class PNItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem {

    public:
        int type() { return TypePNItem; }
    ...

};
```

Which would then allow you to do this:

```
QGraphicsItem *item = scene->itemAt( x, y );
switch( item->type() )
{
    case PNItem:
         ...
         break;
}
```

doing this also enables the usage of [qgraphicsitem_cast](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#qgraphicsitem_cast)

See also: [QGraphicsItem::UserType](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#UserType-var)

Answer (score 4):

Since you've only got two types, you could just use `dynamic_cast`ing, and check to see if the cast was successful:

```
QGraphicsItem *item = scene->ItemAt(pos);
PNEdge *as_pnedge;
PNItem *as_pnitem;
if((as_pnedge = dynamic_cast<PNEdge*>(item))){
    // do stuff with as_pnedge
}else if((as_pnitem = dynamic_cast<PNItem*>(item))){
    // do stuff with as_pnitem
}
```